# change customer address field

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

By default magento customer address, when we selected `Country USA, State/Province will show drop down with all state list,`

but other country showing just normal text field.

**In case i want to insert State/Province for my country as dropdown option, how can I do ?**

or it require custom code/ extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you can do by running some sql on ur database system.

Magento basically save  ***region/state*** detail at *`directory_country_region`* & *`directory_country_region_name`* table.

So you need to sql query at those table.

**See some reference of  India example:**

- [Adding the India States list in Magento](http://zudioz.com/blog/entry/30-adding-the-india-states-list-in-magento.html)
- [excellencemagentoblog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/31/magento-add-state-country-indian-states/)